# How to deploy legacy developer portal customized content from one instance to another?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have done changes to the content of legacy developer portal and i want to deploy the same changes to another instance so is there any way that we can deploy from one instance to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look Git integration option
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git

The portalStyles folder contains configuration and style sheets for developer portal customizations for the service instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will only provides portalStyles and portalTemplate but no options for widgets and image content so do you have any idea for moving widgets as well. any other approaches like using ARM templates.

Comment: What kind of widgets are you talking about? As I know the legacy portal does not have widgets.

Comment: I mean customization of Publisher portal(Manage content and Media files).

Comment: Yes, this part can be moved only by copy from one instance to another. 
You can check the new dev portal, you can easily move customization from one instance to another.
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/wiki/Migrate-portal-between-services